# Using default boot option "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic" leads to slowness and multiple monitor errors

Tags: boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors

My desktop has two pretty new SSD hard drives (a couple months old each). One of them has `Windows 10` which I use for gaming, the other has `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS` which I use for work. CPU is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50GHz`, RAM is `32 GB DDR4`, graphics card is a `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070`, and motherboard is a `MSI MS7972`. I have dual monitors attached directly to graphics card output, one in a DVI the other in a DisplayPort.

Up until today this desktop worked fine without a hitch (built in late 2016, two SSDs are the only new parts since first build). It even worked fine yesterday evening. This morning though, I boot up with the default Ubuntu option and my second monitor isn't detected, additionally the system is running EXTREMELY slow. I boot into Windows and everything is working fast and both monitors are detected and running just fine. Even start up Witcher 3 and run it a bit to make sure everything is going smooth. I boot again, this time choosing advance Ubuntu options and running `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic`. Again the system is EXTREMELY slow and only one monitor is detected. So I instead I boot up again with `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-62-generic`. Now both monitors are detected and it is running as fast as ever.

I did some searching and found some threads with people suggesting an investigation of any BIOS settings that might be slowing down the CPU. I couldn't find any settings that seemed like they would slow it down and I couldn't find a similar question anywhere. I assume the issue is related to an update but I'm not sure how/what caused it. I'm concerned that as new updates comes out, the option `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-62-generic` may also get the same issues for me and then I'll be kind of stuck. For now using `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-62-generic` is fine, but I'd really like my default and the latest startup option to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [Ubuntu bug #1888617](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-435/+bug/1888617). The proprietary nvidia-driver-435 does not build with kernel 5.4.0-42.

To fix, upgrade the nvidia driver:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

This should install the latest driver. Reboot, boot kernel 5.4.0, and everything should work again.

To check which nvidia drivers are available for your graphics card:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001C20sv00001A58sd00002001bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

To check installed driver:

```
$ dpkg -l 'nvidia-driver*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                  Version         Architecture    Description
+++-=====================-===============-===============-================================================
ii  nvidia-driver-440     440.100-0ubuntu amd64           NVIDIA driver metapackage
```